# Flink doesn't fail job on checkpoints failure

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

According to Apache Flink documentation there is a parameter [failOnCheckpointingErrors](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/environment/CheckpointConfig.html#isFailOnCheckpointingErrors--) (currently deprecated but still supported), if it's true job should fail if it's unable to create checkpoint (timeout or exception). But in reality it doesn't happen.

Can anyone point me where I'm wrong in my assumptions?

Answer (score 1):

Job will fail only in case of `CHECKPOINT_DECLINED` what happens if the was an exception during checkpoint execution.
If checkpoint didn't succeed because of timeout the cause is `CHECKPOINT_EXPIRED` which doesn't increment failure count.